# error geting POST from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

when i try to retrieve a specific POST value, i get some problems.

my ajax code:

```
var _data = $('#activateForm').serialize() + "&1=" + name1 + "&2=" + name2;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./do.php",
    data: _data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
    ...
```

PHP code:

```
$ball = $_POST['ball'];
```

(this "ball" is a element on `$('#activateForm').serialize())`

the result of this is all the `_data` string, not just the "ball" value.

like: ball=dsds&1=ddd&2=ddfd

how can i get a specific value?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do this.. I think you should first remove the stuff you are appending after the serialization in jQuery and see if it works.

If it doesn't. try This:

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_REQUEST, $params);
```

Comment: yea it works, but i need to add this other 2 items. how could i do? (ill try this code)

Comment: Add two hidden fields <input type="hidden" name="l" value="Whatever" /> and another for your other, so it all gets serialized consistently.

Comment: ok, how can i put like to serialized items together? like: $('#activateForm').serialize() + $('#blahblah').serialize()

Comment: Not sure why you are doing that when the hidden fields will fix it, but you can look at how the guy does it here (He uses an object): http://www.jblotus.com/2011/07/12/combine-serialized-form-post-data-with-arbitrary-object-in-jquery/

Comment: awesome! this probably gonna help me! thanks. btw, im doing that because i cant add all elements to the same form

Comment: But it should already be in the form, Im tellin ya hidden values are the way to go.. And if necessary, populate those hiddens fields through JavaScript. But whatever works!